# removing read only attribute for files and folders after getting latest version in VS 2012 every time

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using TFS and VS 2012

Whenever i am getting latest version the files get the read-only attribute and i have to close the Visual studio and remove the read only and then open the solution again and re-build it

Is this a Mandatory process or is there a way out of this? 
I dont want readonly attribute to be added when I get latest version

Comment: TFS uses the read only flag to track which files are checked out and to prevent you from changing them unless you have them checked out.  The IDE should (by default) automatically check out any file you attempt to modify and then mark it read only again after you check it in.  Are you getting some kind of error that you think you need to mark the file as read/write?  If so, what error are you getting and what are you trying to do when you get it?

Comment: the DLLs of BAL DAL are not getting built

Comment: See @MrHinsh's answer below, which is what I would have answered if I had been awake at the time.

Answer (score 5):

You should never check DLL's or other compile time generated files into source control. This will prevent the need to remove the read-only flag.

If you are using a Web Site then VS will automatically add your DLL's. Web Sites is a deprecated technology and should not be used. Upgrade instead to a Web Application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx

You can also upgrade in place by creating a new web app and dropping the .*proj file into the same directory as your web site and then following the linked instructions.

Answer (score 4):

In TFS 2012 they introduced something called local Workspaces.  If you go into your workspace configuration screen, make sure you have your workspace set to Local instead of Server.  This will stop VS/TFS from ever setting the read-only flag.

Comment: However it does not stop it from checking in binaries. That is a product of the old WebSite technology...

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue my self.  I copied a file and wanted to create a version 2. This is something I did a lot i a previous company, but not at my current one.  However in my previous company we didn't use the TFS check in process.

Checked in through TFS - pulled the latest version of the build, closed it down, opened the file, all worked ok.  You may not have to close it down, but checking in the file and obtaining the latest build sure seemed to work for me